# unknown custom metadata item kind 7 when using .Net Reactor

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, reverse-engineering, deobfuscation

Till the present moment I was using **PreEmptive Dotfuscator** to obfuscate my assemblies until I've found THE GREAT .Net Reactor solution for the same purpose, I tired Reactor and it was really amazing until I fall down in the hole!!
Reactor worked greatly in most of my assemblies but when I've tried my recent C# solution I had the following error:

[image: unknown custom metadata item kind 7 .net reactor]

My solution is C# .Net 3.5, Reactor version: 4.4.7.5

Any help present?

Comment: Does that obfuscator have a feature to produce invalid metadata? You might try disabling that to see if the result is more usable.

Comment: @LonelyPixel produce invalid metadata?!! may I have misunderstood you.
In general, the .Net Reactor doesn't provide a feature like that.
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have  you tried to delete all the debug files (.pdb) before you protect the assembly?

Comment: AMAZING MAN !!!! It worked!!
Could you tell me please why the *.pdb affected this operation?
Although some of my assemblies worked with Reactor without deleting its .pdb file?

Comment: The unknown debug symbol is in the file.  I suspect your version of visual studio is more advanced than the (old) version of .net reactor you are using. This was suggested by their tech support and worked for me.  [except for my .net version was too advanced so I've got to upgrade anyway]

Comment: Exactly, because I've tried Reactor v4.9.9 and I didn't get that annoying error, knowing that I'm using Visual Studio 2015